# Why can't i paste eveything I copied on Windows cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd

I wrote a code and itried to give it input through cmd and i was not able to paste everything i copied. The text i copied was

```
(~y | ~m | ~g | ~S | V | ~K | ~T | ~J | ~v | ~U | ~L | ~t | ~D | ~o | ~k | ~s | ~o | ~C | ~A | ~D | ~H | ~C | ~n | ~H | ~o | ~U | ~a | ~Q) & (~y | ~u | ~y | ~B | ~d | ~H | ~n | ~Y | ~i | ~E | ~z | ~b | ~n | ~n | ~V | ~K | ~v | ~w | ~k | ~i | ~J | ~z | ~m | ~C | ~w | ~U | ~H | ~m | ~K | ~w | ~G | ~l | ~u | ~T | ~y | ~V | ~R | ~Y | ~F | ~g | ~A | ~Q | ~M | ~z | ~e | ~X | ~X | ~n | ~j | ~s | ~q) & (~t | ~d | ~o | ~c | ~S | ~y | ~L | ~M | ~h | ~S | ~H | ~Y | ~h | ~l | ~a | ~C | ~w | ~L | ~Y | ~f | ~c | ~v | ~v | ~T | ~s | ~h) & (~D | ~V | ~c | ~X | ~R | Y | ~X | ~q | ~S | ~d | ~P | ~J | ~K | ~I | ~u | ~v | ~Z | ~o | ~M | ~X | ~i | ~z | ~k | ~g | ~J | ~C | ~w | ~C) & (~v | ~S | ~j | ~s | ~x | ~e | ~R | ~G | ~Q | ~E | ~O | ~k | ~f | ~D | ~Z | ~S | ~y | ~X | ~G | ~w | ~M | ~j | U | ~k | ~m | ~V | ~b | ~a | ~a | ~E | ~b | ~N) & (~X | ~e | ~Q | ~X | ~T | ~R | ~c | ~K | ~A | ~u | ~u | ~n | ~c | ~k | ~H | ~k | ~A | ~S | ~x | ~X | ~R | ~Z | ~u | ~C | ~G | ~c | ~t | ~X | ~w | ~S | ~c | ~o | ~Q | ~E | ~X | ~U) & (~B | ~W | ~O | ~i | ~m | ~c | ~c | ~U | ~q | ~O | ~d | ~p | ~k | ~J | ~I | ~M | ~f | ~V | ~S | ~e | ~U | ~P | ~k | ~B | ~G | ~j | ~K | ~G | ~n) & (~R | ~x | ~O | ~D | ~e | ~u | ~B | ~n | ~L | ~W | ~q | ~T | ~y | ~Y | ~b | ~z | ~c | ~F | ~R | ~i | ~s | ~D | ~I | ~x | ~h | ~h | ~F | ~V | ~T | ~D | ~N | ~l | ~u | ~e | ~p | ~V) & (~t | ~v | ~P | ~W | ~X | ~B | ~G | ~i | ~B | k | ~M | ~q | ~G | ~r | ~b | ~C) & (~U | ~O | ~s | ~I | ~n | ~E | ~i | ~e | ~P | ~x | ~w | ~B | ~s | ~t | ~y | ~U | ~D | ~R | ~Y | ~o | ~M | ~e | ~d | ~p | ~J | ~k | ~p | ~g | ~H | ~v | ~J | ~A | ~j | ~Y | ~s | ~q | ~D | ~k | ~d | ~N | ~A | ~W) & (~R | U | ~z | ~M | ~C | ~B | ~K | ~J | ~F | ~D | ~J | ~e | ~n | ~l | ~E | ~Z | ~O | ~t | ~Y | ~f | ~x) & (~A | ~q | ~M | ~B | ~m | ~D | ~N | ~r | ~w | ~t | ~l | v) & (~n | ~x | ~Q | v | ~d | ~A | ~T | ~P | ~J | ~h) & (~k | ~i | ~J | ~Q | ~v) & (~t | ~c | ~q | ~x) & (~I | ~v | ~M | ~g | ~g | ~E | ~O | ~n | ~M | ~T | ~h | ~v | ~X | ~D | ~B | ~R | ~U | ~A | ~g | ~h | ~o | ~j | ~i | ~o | ~p | ~W | ~h | ~X | ~H | ~X | ~K | ~w | ~h | ~x | ~q | ~j | ~v | ~n | ~N | ~d | ~e | ~n | ~k | ~s | ~C | ~V | ~l | ~b | ~S | ~m | ~r) & (~e) & (~J | ~P | ~t | ~x | ~m | ~h | ~D | ~W | ~t | ~n | ~r | ~p | ~O | ~p | ~u | ~H | k | ~u | ~z | ~O | ~I | ~t | ~d | ~f | ~Y | ~U | ~S | ~N | ~u | ~K | ~N | ~H | ~t | ~D | ~V | ~a | ~b | ~d | ~P | ~M | ~A | ~s | ~m | ~q | ~U | ~a | ~y) & (~s | ~p | ~B | ~O | ~A | ~P | ~L | ~h | ~g | ~I | ~I | ~j | ~n | ~v | ~U | ~S | ~u | ~V | ~c | ~f | ~E | ~V | ~S | ~h | ~y | ~G) & (~b | ~S | ~O | ~V | ~s | ~A | ~e | ~C | ~S | ~M | ~I | ~M | ~C | ~X | ~Q | ~Q | ~I | ~q | ~e | ~K | ~n | ~a | ~I | ~u | ~U | ~J | ~y | ~E | ~M | ~F | ~J | ~H | ~N | ~U | ~G | ~A | ~o | ~j | ~m | ~Z | ~K | ~G | ~M) & (~U | ~R | ~T | ~q | ~C | ~i | ~m | ~H | ~E | ~q | ~z | ~E | ~l) & (~u | ~o | ~k | ~h | ~v | ~k | ~M | ~z | ~X | ~s | ~v | ~s | ~t | ~Q | ~g | ~Z | ~Y | ~E | ~S | ~S | ~m | ~G | ~U | ~u | ~H | ~k | ~m | ~o | ~d | ~Y | ~q | ~I | ~W | ~b | ~B | ~a | ~p | ~R | ~K | ~X | ~s | ~y | ~X | ~R | ~O | ~t | ~I | ~G | ~O) & (~x | W | ~U | ~S | ~j | ~Q | ~l | ~P) & (~D | ~G | ~d | ~t | ~i | ~G | ~P | ~f | ~q | ~k | ~T | ~w | ~D | ~v | ~I | ~u | ~i | ~O | ~R | ~W | ~Q | ~h | ~t | ~t | ~D | ~S | ~A | ~V | ~R | ~f | ~J | ~U | ~s | ~h | ~E | ~c | ~h | ~M | ~W | ~U | ~C | ~Q | ~w | ~G | ~S | ~L | ~y | ~Q | ~D | ~t | ~o) & (~K | ~G | ~Y | ~l | ~S | ~D | ~x | ~Q | ~R | ~M | ~K | ~c | ~R | ~G | ~n | ~P | ~Q | ~b | ~q | ~t | ~S | ~P | ~L | ~W | ~y | ~h | ~Y | ~P | ~K | ~N | ~M | ~L | ~H | ~H | ~w | ~c | ~M | ~T | ~U | ~I | ~o | ~S | ~v | ~Q) & (~S | ~z | G | ~v | ~S | ~R | ~t | ~i | ~R | ~G | ~u | ~b | ~w | ~a | ~e | ~M | ~w | ~R | ~Z | ~V) & (~T | ~B | ~d | ~Q | ~j | ~R | ~E | ~L | ~v | ~C | ~D | ~H | ~S | ~R | ~A | ~S | ~P | ~s) & (~I | ~W | ~J | ~s | ~w | ~O | ~M | ~J | p | ~X | ~Q | ~M | ~b | ~D | ~z | ~s | ~s | ~B | ~a | ~y | ~j | ~b | ~L) & (~s | ~D | ~I | ~J | ~l | ~W | ~C | ~Z | ~R | ~G | ~K | ~H | ~E | ~V | ~H | ~F | ~J | p | ~A) & (~Z | ~N | ~l | ~b | ~k | ~I | ~y | ~x | ~N | ~B | ~X | ~k | ~S | ~j | ~t | ~E | ~Y | ~g | ~g | ~v | ~U | ~l | ~i | ~z | ~l | ~Y | ~v | ~H | ~D | ~m | ~q | ~a | y | ~L | ~u | ~h | ~L) & (~R | ~b | ~k | k | ~n | ~E | ~G | ~s | ~L | ~P | ~b) & (~i | ~F | ~f | ~R | ~I | ~g | P | ~o | ~T | ~s | ~N | ~h | ~n | ~P | ~J | ~G | ~e | ~D | ~j | ~r | ~R | ~D | ~b | ~i | ~o | ~U | ~G | ~r | ~L | ~y | ~z | ~c | ~z | ~V) & (~r | ~r | ~j | ~m | ~a | ~E | ~a | ~f | ~Q | ~B | ~O | ~Y | X | ~L | ~g | ~y | ~t | ~V) & (~b | ~Z | ~H | ~j | ~i | ~q | ~F | O | ~B | ~h | ~Q | ~k | ~P | ~Z | ~m | ~Y | ~V | ~K | ~p | ~j | ~D) & (~V | ~W | ~s | ~T | ~D | ~M | ~l | ~l | ~Y | t | ~s | ~I | ~w | ~K | ~w | ~D | ~W | ~P | ~n | ~w | ~Q | ~t | ~D | ~N | ~A | ~G | ~g) & (~x | ~v | ~F | ~Y | ~K | ~U | ~N | ~e | ~b | ~k | ~v | ~l | ~C | ~w | ~b | ~V | ~v | ~G | ~L | ~e | ~t | ~I | ~U | ~A | ~T | ~z | ~T | ~X | ~l | ~C | ~I | ~X | ~M | ~k | ~y | ~p | ~w | ~z | ~r | ~k | ~I | ~J | ~U | ~V | ~K) & (~c | ~c | ~s | ~O | ~m | ~a | ~G | ~A | ~H | C | ~L | ~T | ~T | ~a | ~y | ~A | ~F | ~U | ~X | ~s | ~u | ~z | ~t | ~H | ~i | ~F | ~I | ~i | ~S | ~e | ~Y | ~l | ~v | ~q | ~Q | ~y | ~F | ~g | ~X | ~I | ~I | ~l | ~p) & (~L | ~P | ~t | ~z | ~o | ~S | ~x | ~O | ~g | ~M | ~D | ~W | ~x | ~K | ~f | ~D | ~v | ~z | ~k | ~V | ~T | ~P | ~B | ~T | ~i | ~I) & (~S | ~I | ~V | ~X | ~P | ~d | ~o | ~x | ~o | ~p | ~I | ~n | ~h | ~P | ~F | ~T | ~w | ~n | ~h | ~m | ~X | ~k | ~T | ~x | ~p | ~Y | ~u | ~M | ~x | ~X | ~q | ~F | ~U | ~P | ~G | ~H | ~i | ~C | ~i | ~f | ~Z | ~T | ~e | ~Y | ~T | ~y | ~e | ~h | ~d | ~i | ~i) & (~H | ~X | ~l | ~s | ~w | ~p | ~S | ~Z | ~S | ~H | ~D | ~E | ~Z | ~g | ~L | ~D | Y | ~t | ~z | ~D | ~U | ~V | ~i | ~Z | ~S | ~i | ~g | ~H | ~f | ~y | ~o | ~B | ~j | ~H | ~v | ~L | ~S | ~k) & (~A | ~N | ~d | ~u | ~X | ~q | ~k | ~w | ~E | ~x | ~w | ~l | ~u | ~x | ~B | ~O | ~v | ~w | ~R | ~S | ~B | ~q | ~O | ~y | ~o | ~D | ~n | ~q | ~o | ~l | ~d | ~M | ~S | ~j | ~T | ~p | ~U | ~X | ~a | ~M | ~P | ~L | ~k | ~N | ~f) & (~H | ~p | ~N | ~t | ~B | ~F | ~U | ~L | ~O | ~s | ~P | ~O | ~b | ~T | ~T | ~e | ~u | ~L | ~w | ~l | ~w | ~o | ~m | ~x | ~C | ~M | ~x | ~X | ~C | ~o | ~Z | ~E | ~c | ~a | ~S | ~t | ~w | ~Y | ~Z | ~U | ~m | ~O | ~g | ~n | ~a | ~L | ~H | ~G) & (~m | ~s | ~V | ~o | ~R | ~K | ~F | ~Q | ~z | ~u | ~k | ~r | ~i | ~N | ~Z | ~W | ~o | ~t | ~u | ~M | ~T | ~A | ~c) & (~n | ~h | ~N | ~F | ~h | ~O | ~i | ~F | ~e | ~n | ~y | ~B | ~j | ~U | ~h | ~e | ~r | ~T | ~d | ~N | ~A | ~t | ~X | ~l | ~h | ~N | ~P | ~D | ~s | ~q | ~k | ~w | ~x | ~f | ~y | ~H | ~B | ~b | ~C | ~u | ~Q | ~l | ~h | ~m | ~l | ~K | ~S | ~g | ~s | ~L | ~Z | ~T) & (~i | ~o | e | ~z | ~e | ~n | ~x | ~I | ~L | ~m | ~H | ~O | ~s | ~y | ~g | ~e | ~u | ~e | ~W) & (~W | ~O | ~p | ~o | ~a | ~e | ~J | ~L | ~p | ~l | ~K | ~D | ~R | ~Q | ~Q | ~x | ~K | ~r | ~e | ~d | ~S | ~W | ~c | ~q | ~D | ~D | ~E | ~a | ~n | ~d | ~b | ~l | ~x | ~Q | ~P | ~L | ~H | ~n | ~a | ~x | ~x | ~Y | ~K | ~A | ~q | ~B | ~m | ~q | ~k | ~R | ~f | ~h) & (~a | ~n | ~Z | ~A | ~W | ~S | ~O | ~V | ~g | ~G | ~K | ~d | ~Z | ~u | ~j | ~S | ~H | ~v | ~a | ~V | ~g | ~G | ~F | ~D | ~n | ~w | ~W | ~W | ~q | ~u | ~C | ~Y | ~C | ~p | ~r | ~v | ~z | ~A | ~P | ~Y | ~s | ~C | ~u | ~g | ~X | ~y | ~Z | ~K | ~N | ~C) & (~h | ~G | ~d | ~g | ~o | ~j | ~B | ~X | ~w | ~h | ~U | ~W | ~T | ~H | ~E | ~J | ~y | ~j | ~Y | ~y | ~u | ~O | ~j | ~b | ~B | ~D | ~M | ~S | ~k | ~Z | ~E | ~m | ~j | ~R | ~G | ~M | ~W | ~g | ~Q | ~A | ~O | ~Y | ~u | ~P | ~H | ~A | ~a) & (~p | ~N | ~w | ~Q | ~y | ~I | ~z | ~s | ~l | ~e | ~x | ~c | ~O | ~L | ~M | ~h | ~D | ~O | ~d | ~D | G | ~I | ~l | ~a | ~J | ~q | ~L | ~O | ~N | ~M | ~Q | ~h | ~o | ~A | ~d | ~a | ~O | ~H) & (~g | ~W | ~G | ~n | H | ~J | ~h | ~g | ~k) & (~y | ~M | ~J | ~F | ~D | ~f | H | ~m | ~h | ~y | ~N | ~o | ~H | ~v | ~B | ~r | ~W | ~b | ~a) & (~H | ~K | ~m | ~u | ~x | ~H | ~l | ~R | ~W | ~b | ~m | ~F | ~L | ~q | ~p | ~Y | ~l | ~z | ~M | ~X | ~X | ~O | ~F | ~s | ~i | ~G | ~H | ~K | ~A | ~y | ~O | ~y | ~p | ~w | ~V | ~b) & (~h | ~X | ~N | ~Q | ~A | ~Y | ~X | ~L | ~C | ~B | ~P | ~T | ~l | ~I | ~V | ~z | ~u | ~M | ~G | ~l) & (~W | ~r | ~d | ~y | ~F | ~T | C | ~k | ~N | ~z | ~G | ~E | ~y | ~i | ~c | ~J | ~u | ~X | ~Z | ~V | ~W | ~Z | ~O | ~y | ~d | ~o | ~p | ~s | ~z | ~e | ~R | ~I | ~Q | ~X | ~E | ~B | ~i | ~M | ~E | ~q | ~H | ~I | ~Y | ~p | ~M) & (~G | ~j | ~b | ~j | ~X | ~s | ~K | ~V | ~D | ~w | ~U | ~L | ~E | ~P | ~U | ~g | ~e | ~O | ~i | ~x | ~t | ~m | ~P | ~t | ~p | ~B | ~E | ~S | ~L | ~Y | ~M | ~A | ~H) & (~U | ~c | ~Q | ~d | ~z | ~K | ~t | ~g | ~x | ~o | ~r | ~J | ~n | ~D | ~O | ~l | ~O | ~Q | ~K | ~r | ~Q | ~z | ~G | ~O | ~e | ~Z | ~o | ~D | ~O) & (~K | ~U | ~U | ~s | ~J | ~w | ~B | ~r | ~R | ~q | ~q | ~D | ~N | ~b | ~J | ~t | ~F | ~D | ~H | ~N | ~a | ~z | ~c | ~Z | ~Z | ~g | ~a | ~g | ~n | ~d | ~d | ~M | ~G) & (~W | ~Q | ~k | ~m | ~K | ~z | ~o | ~o | ~z | ~k | ~x | ~T | ~p | ~S | ~C | ~l | ~S | ~X | ~n | ~j | ~D | ~W | ~w | ~W | ~X | ~w | ~W | ~M | ~a | ~F | ~y | ~W | ~T | ~G | ~k | ~B | ~d | ~m | ~i | ~H | ~C | ~k | ~P | ~W | ~D | ~m) & (~p | ~T | ~t | ~P | ~n | ~k | ~A | ~n | ~Z | ~i | ~l | ~W | ~b | ~O | ~l | ~e | ~f | ~B | T | ~D | ~j | ~q | ~X) & (~c | ~V | ~a | ~E | ~i | ~G | ~X | ~L) & (~f | ~A | ~P | ~F | ~n | ~S | ~p | ~e | ~L | ~K | ~E | ~Y | ~h | ~M | ~b | ~u | ~y | ~a | ~E | ~o | ~k | ~B | ~X | ~k | ~V | ~O | ~R | ~e | ~X | ~h | ~K | ~g | ~W | ~f | ~w) & (~f | ~c | ~Z | ~Y | ~p | ~n | ~i | ~e | ~N | ~a | ~y | ~d | ~v | ~z | ~p | ~H | ~f | ~S | ~E | ~Z | ~S | ~Z | ~w | ~V | ~U | ~T | ~g | ~y | ~B | ~H) & (~I | ~w | ~p | ~P | ~p | ~r | ~m | ~O | ~q | ~r | ~u | ~G | ~u | ~t | ~C | ~B | ~L | ~k | ~x | ~S | ~Q | ~a | ~X | ~o | ~v | ~t | ~O | ~M | ~m | ~M | ~Y | ~E | ~P | ~D | ~m | ~U | ~V | ~y | ~z | ~f | ~I) & (~H | ~k | ~N | ~R | ~H | ~s | ~U | ~T | ~O | ~W | ~M | ~t | ~p | ~e | ~p | ~k | ~s | ~r | ~P | ~e | ~o | ~C | ~Y) & (~w | ~f | ~e | ~c | ~n | ~N | ~A | ~U | ~z | ~p | ~D | ~r | ~d | ~B | ~V | ~J | ~h | ~A | ~b | ~R | ~S | ~T | ~b | ~b | ~p | ~x | ~H | ~r | ~E | ~B | ~l | ~S) & (~L | ~x | ~b | ~i | ~S | ~C | ~s | Y | ~Q | ~A | ~V | ~t | ~f | ~g | ~l | ~G | ~u | ~z | ~P | ~s | ~Y | ~s | ~m | ~b | ~h | ~O | ~Q | ~p | ~e | ~i | ~P | ~G | ~I | ~F) & (~h | ~c | ~t | ~x | ~k | ~X | ~h | ~k | ~y | ~c | ~z | ~j | ~h | ~p | ~S | ~X | ~P | ~y) & (~E | ~Q | ~e | ~O | ~G | ~n | ~o | ~K | ~K | ~E | ~Z | ~H | ~i | ~j | ~U | ~r | ~w | ~E | ~Y | ~L | ~Q | ~v | ~y | ~z | ~R | ~K | ~i | ~D | ~d | ~j | ~C | ~q | ~J | ~u | ~F | ~q) & (~W | ~q | ~n | ~L | ~d | ~Z | ~E | ~b | ~I | ~c | ~a | ~y | ~a | ~b | ~D | ~e | ~a | ~u) & (~J | ~E | ~j | ~k | ~d | ~M | ~i | ~t | ~c | ~U | ~r | ~p | ~Y | ~x | ~c | ~L | ~c | ~a | ~x | ~N | ~H) & (~J | ~x | ~I | ~m | ~B | ~p | ~V | ~B | ~C | ~r | ~t | ~W | ~u | ~M | ~K | ~y | ~s | ~f | ~z | ~m | ~R | ~D | ~Z | ~e | ~n | ~y | ~U | ~t | ~g | ~y | ~U | ~j | ~h | ~z | ~v | ~q | ~s | ~F | ~n | ~r | ~e | ~w | ~Y | ~w) & (e)
```

This text contains 10853 characters.
But when i pasted it on cmd only this much is printed.

```
(~y | ~m | ~g | ~S | V | ~K | ~T | ~J | ~v | ~U | ~L | ~t | ~D | ~o | ~k | ~s | ~o | ~C | ~A | ~D | ~H | ~C | ~n | ~H | ~o | ~U | ~a | ~Q) & (~y | ~u | ~y | ~B | ~d | ~H | ~n | ~Y | ~i | ~E | ~z | ~b | ~n | ~n | ~V | ~K | ~v | ~w | ~k | ~i | ~J | ~z | ~m | ~C | ~w | ~U | ~H | ~m | ~K | ~w | ~G | ~l | ~u | ~T | ~y | ~V | ~R | ~Y | ~F | ~g | ~A | ~Q | ~M | ~z | ~e | ~X | ~X | ~n | ~j | ~s | ~q) & (~t | ~d | ~o | ~c | ~S | ~y | ~L | ~M | ~h | ~S | ~H | ~Y | ~h | ~l | ~a | ~C | ~w | ~L | ~Y | ~f | ~c | ~v | ~v | ~T | ~s | ~h) & (~D | ~V | ~c | ~X | ~R | Y | ~X | ~q | ~S | ~d | ~P | ~J | ~K | ~I | ~u | ~v | ~Z | ~o | ~M | ~X | ~i | ~z | ~k | ~g | ~J | ~C | ~w | ~C) & (~v | ~S | ~j | ~s | ~x | ~e | ~R | ~G | ~Q | ~E | ~O | ~k | ~f | ~D | ~Z | ~S | ~y | ~X | ~G | ~w | ~M | ~j | U | ~k | ~m | ~V | ~b | ~a | ~a | ~E | ~b | ~N) & (~X | ~e | ~Q | ~X | ~T | ~R | ~c | ~K | ~A | ~u | ~u | ~n | ~c | ~k | ~H | ~k | ~A | ~S | ~x | ~X | ~R | ~Z | ~u | ~C | ~G | ~c | ~t | ~X | ~w | ~S | ~c | ~o | ~Q | ~E | ~X | ~U) & (~B | ~W | ~O | ~i | ~m | ~c | ~c | ~U | ~q | ~O | ~d | ~p | ~k | ~J | ~I | ~M | ~f | ~V | ~S | ~e | ~U | ~P | ~k | ~B | ~G | ~j | ~K | ~G | ~n) & (~R | ~x | ~O | ~D | ~e | ~u | ~B | ~n | ~L | ~W | ~q | ~T | ~y | ~Y | ~b | ~z | ~c | ~F | ~R | ~i | ~s | ~D | ~I | ~x | ~h | ~h | ~F | ~V | ~T | ~D | ~N | ~l | ~u | ~e | ~p | ~V) & (~t | ~v | ~P | ~W | ~X | ~B | ~G | ~i | ~B | k | ~M | ~q | ~G | ~r | ~b | ~C) & (~U | ~O | ~s | ~I | ~n | ~E | ~i | ~e | ~P | ~x | ~w | ~B | ~s | ~t | ~y | ~U | ~D | ~R | ~Y | ~o | ~M | ~e | ~d | ~p | ~J | ~k | ~p | ~g | ~H | ~v | ~J | ~A | ~j | ~Y | ~s | ~q | ~D | ~k | ~d | ~N | ~A | ~W) & (~R | U | ~z | ~M | ~C | ~B | ~K | ~J | ~F | ~D | ~J | ~e | ~n | ~l | ~E | ~Z | ~O | ~t | ~Y | ~f | ~x) & (~A | ~q | ~M | ~B | ~m | ~D | ~N | ~r | ~w | ~t | ~l | v) & (~n | ~x | ~Q | v | ~d | ~A | ~T | ~P | ~J | ~h) & (~k | ~i | ~J | ~Q | ~v) & (~t | ~c | ~q | ~x) & (~I | ~v | ~M | ~g | ~g | ~E | ~O | ~n | ~M | ~T | ~h | ~v | ~X | ~D | ~B | ~R | ~U | ~A | ~g | ~h | ~o | ~j | ~i | ~o | ~p | ~W | ~h | ~X | ~H | ~X | ~K | ~w | ~h | ~x | ~q | ~j | ~v | ~n | ~N | ~d | ~e | ~n | ~k | ~s | ~C | ~V | ~l | ~b | ~S | ~m | ~r) & (~e) & (~J | ~P | ~t | ~x | ~m | ~h | ~D | ~W | ~t | ~n | ~r | ~p | ~O | ~p | ~u | ~H | k | ~u | ~z | ~O | ~I | ~t | ~d | ~f | ~Y | ~U | ~S | ~N | ~u | ~K | ~N | ~H | ~t | ~D | ~V | ~a | ~b | ~d | ~P | ~M | ~A | ~s | ~m | ~q | ~U | ~a | ~y) & (~s | ~p | ~B | ~O | ~A | ~P | ~L | ~h | ~g | ~I | ~I | ~j | ~n | ~v | ~U | ~S | ~u | ~V | ~c | ~f | ~E | ~V | ~S | ~h | ~y | ~G) & (~b | ~S | ~O | ~V | ~s | ~A | ~e | ~C | ~S | ~M | ~I | ~M | ~C | ~X | ~Q | ~Q | ~I | ~q | ~e | ~K | ~n | ~a | ~I | ~u | ~U | ~J | ~y | ~E | ~M | ~F | ~J | ~H | ~N | ~U | ~G | ~A | ~o | ~j | ~m | ~Z | ~K | ~G | ~M) & (~U | ~R | ~T | ~q | ~C | ~i | ~m | ~H | ~E | ~q | ~z | ~E | ~l) & (~u | ~o | ~k | ~h | ~v | ~k | ~M | ~z | ~X | ~s | ~v | ~s | ~t | ~Q | ~g | ~Z | ~Y | ~E | ~S | ~S | ~m | ~G | ~U | ~u | ~H | ~k | ~m | ~o | ~d | ~Y | ~q | ~I | ~W | ~b | ~B | ~a | ~p | ~R | ~K | ~X | ~s | ~y | ~X | ~R | ~O | ~t | ~I | ~G | ~O) & (~x | W | ~U | ~S | ~j | ~Q | ~l | ~P) & (~D | ~G | ~d | ~t | ~i | ~G | ~P | ~f | ~q | ~k | ~T | ~w | ~D | ~v | ~I | ~u | ~i | ~O | ~R | ~W | ~Q | ~h | ~t | ~t | ~D | ~S | ~A | ~V | ~R | ~f | ~J | ~U | ~s | ~h | ~E | ~c | ~h | ~M | ~W | ~U | ~C | ~Q | ~w | ~G | ~S | ~L | ~y | ~Q | ~D | ~t | ~o) & (~K | ~G | ~Y | ~l | ~S | ~D | ~x | ~Q | ~R | ~M | ~K | ~c | ~R | ~G | ~n | ~P | ~Q | ~b | ~q | ~t | ~S | ~P | ~L | ~W | ~y | ~h | ~Y | ~P | ~K | ~N | ~M | ~L | ~H | ~H | ~w | ~c | ~M | ~T | ~U | ~I | ~o | ~S | ~v | ~Q) & (~S | ~z | G | ~v | ~S | ~R | ~t | ~i | ~R | ~G | ~u | ~b | ~w | ~a | ~e | ~M | ~w | ~R | ~Z | ~V) & (~T | ~B | ~d | ~Q | ~j | ~R | ~E | ~L | ~v | ~C | ~D | ~H | ~S | ~R | ~A | ~S | ~P | ~s) & (~I | ~W | ~J | ~s | ~w | ~O | ~M | ~J | p | ~X | ~Q | ~M | ~b | ~D | ~z | ~s | ~s | ~B | ~a | ~y | ~j | ~b | ~L) & (~s | ~D | ~I | ~J | ~l | ~W | ~C | ~Z | ~R | ~G | ~K | ~H | ~E | ~V | ~H | ~F | ~J | p | ~A) & (~Z | ~N | ~l | ~b | ~k | ~I | ~y | ~x | ~N | ~B | ~X | ~k | ~S | ~j | ~t | ~E | ~Y | ~g | ~g | ~v | ~U | ~l | ~i | ~z | ~l | ~Y | ~v | ~H | ~D | ~m | ~q | ~a | y | ~L | ~u | ~h | ~L) & (~R | ~b | ~k | k | ~n | ~E | ~G | ~s | ~L | ~P | ~b) & (~i | ~F | ~f | ~R | ~I | ~g | P | ~o | ~T | ~s | ~N | ~h | ~n | ~P | ~J | ~G | ~e | ~D | ~j | ~r | ~R | ~D | ~b | ~i | ~o | ~U | ~G | ~r | ~L | ~y | ~z | ~c | ~z | ~V) & (~r | ~r | ~j | ~m | ~a | ~E | ~a | ~f | ~Q | ~B | ~O | ~Y | X | ~L | ~g | ~y | ~t | ~V) & (~b | ~Z | ~H | ~j | ~i | ~q | ~F | O | ~B | ~h | ~Q | ~k | ~P | ~Z | ~m | ~Y | ~V | ~K | ~p | ~j | ~D) & (~V | ~W | ~s | ~T | ~D | ~M | ~l | ~l | ~Y | t | ~s | ~I | ~w | ~K | ~w | ~D | ~W | ~P | ~n | ~w | ~Q | ~t | ~D | ~N | ~A | ~G | ~g) & (~x | ~v | ~F | ~Y | ~K | ~U | ~N | ~e | ~b | ~k | ~v | ~l | ~C | ~w | ~b | ~V | ~v | ~G | ~L | ~e | ~t | ~I | ~U | ~A | ~T | ~z | ~T | ~X | ~l | ~C | ~I | ~X | ~M | ~k | ~y | ~p | ~w | ~z | ~r | ~k | ~I | ~J | ~U | ~V | ~K) & (~c | ~c | ~s | ~O | ~m | ~a | ~G | ~A | ~H | C | ~L | ~T | ~T | ~a | ~y | ~A | ~F | ~U | ~X | ~s | ~u | ~z | ~t | ~H | ~i | ~F | ~I | ~i | ~S | ~e | ~Y | ~l | ~v | ~q | ~Q | ~y | ~F | ~g | ~X | ~I | ~I | ~l | ~p) & (~L | ~P | ~t | ~z | ~o | ~S | ~x | ~O | ~g | ~M | ~D | ~W | ~x | ~K | ~f | ~D | ~v | ~z | ~k | ~V | ~T | ~P | ~B | ~T | ~i | ~I) & (~S | ~I | ~V | ~X | ~P | ~d | ~o | ~x | ~o | ~p | ~I | ~n | ~h | ~P | ~F | ~T | ~w | ~n | ~h | ~m | ~X | ~k | ~T | ~x | ~p | ~Y | ~u | ~M | ~x | ~X | ~q | ~F | ~U | ~P | ~G | ~H | ~i | ~C | ~i | ~f | ~Z | ~T | ~e | ~Y | ~T | ~y | ~e | ~h | ~d | ~i | ~i) & (~H | ~X | ~l | ~s | ~w | ~p | ~S | ~Z | ~S | ~H | ~D | ~E | ~Z | ~g | ~L | ~D | Y | ~t | ~z | ~D | ~U | ~V | ~i | ~Z | ~S | ~i | ~g | ~H | ~f | ~y | ~o | ~B | ~j | ~H | ~v | ~L | ~S | ~k) & (~A | ~N | ~d | ~u | ~X | ~q | ~k | ~w | ~E | ~x | ~w | ~l | ~u | ~x | ~B | ~O | ~v | ~w | ~R | ~S | ~B | ~q | ~O | ~y | ~o | ~D | ~n | ~q | ~o | ~l | ~d | ~M | ~S | ~j | ~T | ~p | ~U | ~X | ~a | ~M | ~P | ~L | ~k | ~N | ~f) & (~H | ~p | ~N | ~t | ~B | ~F | ~U | ~L | ~O | ~s | ~P | ~O | ~b | ~T | ~T | ~e | ~u | ~L | ~w | ~l | ~w | ~o | ~m | ~x | ~C | ~M | ~x | ~X | ~C | ~o | ~Z | ~E | ~c | ~a | ~S | ~t | ~w | ~Y | ~Z | ~U | ~m | ~O | ~g | ~n | ~a | ~L | ~H | ~G) & (~m | ~s | ~V | ~o | ~R | ~K | ~F | ~Q | ~z | ~u | ~k | ~r | ~i | ~N | ~Z | ~W | ~o | ~t | ~u | ~M | ~T | ~A | ~c) & (~n | ~h | ~N | ~F | ~h | ~O | ~i | ~F | ~e | ~n | ~y | ~B | ~j | ~U | ~h | ~e | ~r | ~T | ~d | ~N | ~A | ~t | ~X | ~l | ~h | ~N | ~P | ~D | ~s | ~q | ~k | ~w | ~x | ~f | ~y | ~H | ~B | ~b | ~C | ~u | ~Q | ~l | ~h | ~m | ~l | ~K | ~S | ~g | ~s | ~L | ~Z | ~T) & (~i | ~o | e | ~z | ~e | ~n | ~x | ~I | ~L | ~m | ~H | ~O | ~s | ~y | ~g | ~e | ~u | ~e | ~W) & (~W | ~O | ~p | ~o | ~a | ~e | ~J | ~L | ~p | ~l | ~K | ~D | ~R | ~Q | ~Q | ~x | ~K | ~r | ~e | ~d | ~S | ~W | ~c | ~q | ~D | ~D | ~E | ~a | ~n | ~d | ~b | ~l | ~x | ~Q | ~P | ~L | ~H | ~n | ~a | ~x | ~x | ~Y | ~K | ~A | ~q | ~B | ~m | ~q | ~k | ~R | ~f | ~h) & (~a | ~n | ~Z | ~A | ~W | ~S | ~O | ~V | ~g | ~G | ~K | ~d | ~Z | ~u | ~j | ~S | ~H | ~v | ~a | ~V | ~g | ~G | ~F | ~D | ~n | ~w | ~W | ~W | ~q | ~u | ~C | ~Y | ~C | ~p | ~r | ~v | ~z | ~A | ~P | ~Y | ~s | ~C | ~u | ~g | ~X | ~y | ~Z | ~K | ~N | ~C) & (~h | ~G | ~d | ~g | ~o | ~j | ~B | ~X | ~w | ~h | ~U | ~W | ~T | ~H | ~E | ~J | ~y | ~j | ~Y | ~y | ~u | ~O | ~j | ~b | ~B | ~D | ~M | ~S | ~k | ~Z | ~E | ~m | ~j | ~R | ~G | ~M | ~W | ~g | ~Q | ~A | ~O | ~Y | ~u | ~P | ~H | ~A | ~a) & (~p | ~N | ~w | ~Q | ~y | ~I | ~z | ~s | ~l | ~e | ~x | ~c | ~O | ~L | ~M | ~h | ~D | ~O | ~d | ~D | G | ~I | ~l | ~a | ~J | ~q | ~L | ~O | ~N | ~M | ~Q | ~h | ~o | ~A | ~d | ~a | ~O | ~H) & (~g | ~W | ~G | ~n | H | ~J | ~h | ~g | ~k) & (~y | ~M | ~J | ~F | ~D | ~f | H | ~m | ~h | ~y | ~N | ~o | ~H | ~v | ~B | ~r | ~W | ~b | ~a) & (~H | ~K | ~m | ~u | ~x | ~H | ~l | ~R | ~W | ~b | ~m | ~F | ~L | ~q | ~p | ~Y | ~l | ~z | ~M | ~X | ~X | ~O | ~F | ~s | ~i | ~G | ~H | ~K | ~A | ~y | ~O | ~y | ~p | ~w | ~V | ~b) & (~h | ~X | ~N | ~Q | ~A | ~Y | ~X | ~L | ~C | ~B | ~P | ~T | ~l | ~I | ~V | ~z | ~u | ~M | ~G | ~l) & (~W | ~r | ~d | ~y | ~F | ~T | C | ~k | ~N | ~z | ~G | ~E | ~y | ~i | ~c | ~J | ~u | ~X | ~Z | ~V | ~W | ~Z | ~O | ~y
```

Which is 8189 characters long.

Comment: Yes, the official limit for `cmd.exe` is (still) `8,191` characters - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/command-line-string-limitation. By contrast, PowerShell, which you should consider switching to in general, supports up to `32,764` chars.

Comment: On a side note: what exactly are you trying to do because what you've posted looks like it could be simplified?